# coreplot: show new data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot

Probably it is quite easy, but I do not find it:
I have some data in a variable "data".
After initialising the scatterplot everything is fine. Then the data of "data" changes. What should I do now. Old solution: release plot and create a new one. It orks, but this is not nice.

What I try:

```
  [self.scatterPlot setGraphData:data];
```

Nothing happens. Therefore I assume I need one more litte step, like "reloading" or "updating", but I cannot find any such possibility.
Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
[[self.scatterPlot] setNeedsDisplay];
```

If you draw your plot inside `drawRect:` this will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

the missing line is:

```
  [[self.ScatterPlot graph] reloadData];
```